# how to remove the white space between two img when convert into oft format?

Tags: html, css

```
<table border="0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" height="50" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;text-align:center;" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p style="background-color:#dedede;line-height:25px;font-family: verdana,sans-serif;font-size:9px;">For more information on delegate registration and sponsorship opportunities</p>
            <img style="margin-top:0;" width="700" height="9" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/28cfx3m.jpg" alt="bottombanner"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWAkp/5/).

In above code there is a white space occurs between that `<p>` & `<img>` tag, when it convert into oft format/email format. How to remove that white space without giving negative values.
thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have css reset?

Comment: There is only one img tag in your code and your questions is - how to remove white space in TWO images....strange...ANd your js fiddel is showing no white spaces...

Comment: sorry sir, its my mistake. actually its one img tag and p tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding vertical-align in img style

```
<img style="margin-top:0; vertical-align:top;" width="700" height="9" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/28cfx3m.jpg" alt="bottombanner"/>
```

Here is jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GWAkp/3/

Edited Code :--- See Edited p style

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" height="50" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;text-align:center;" >
<tr>
    <td>
        <p style="background-color:#dedede;line-height:25px;font-family: verdana,sans-serif;font-size:9px;margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:0px;">For more information on delegate registration and sponsorship opportunities</p>
        <img style="margin-top:0px; vertical-align:top;" width="700" height="9" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/28cfx3m.jpg" alt="bottombanner"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GWAkp/6/

Answer (score 0):

Give `display: block;` to `img`

and `margin: 0` to `p`

CSS

```
img {
    display: block
}
p {
    margin: 0
}
```

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GWAkp/4/)